# MUI Autocomplete, renderInput prop: What is (are) params?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm learning how to use MUI's Autocomplete component, and I'm struggling to understand the `renderInput` prop.  I get that it exists to specify how you're going to display the component, but I don't understand how it works. In particular, what is the `params` object that is passed into the function? What does it contain? How am I supposed to use it?

I've been doing a lot of web searches and have failed to find a good resource to explain this.  The documentation's description of the prop is "Render the input", which drives me a little crazy.

Any help elucidating would be very much appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This is the understanding which I have finally come to.

Posting in case it is of use to others ending up at this question.

### The `renderInput` prop

The key to understanding the `renderInput` prop is realizing that the text input control which forms the core of the `Autocomplete` is ***not*** determined by MUI.   Instead it is ***chosen by you.***

Your choice of text input control is designated in the `renderInput` prop, which is why that prop is required.

The `renderInput` prop is a function which both (i) specifies which text input component to use for the core (commonly an MUI `TextField`) *and* (ii) formats that component.

The function returns the formatted core component, accepting as an argument an object `params` which contains some props supplied from the `Autocomplete`.  The `params` object should be spread inside your returned component.

Example:

```
renderInput={params => <TextField {...params} label="Breed" variant="outlined" />}
```

### The `params` argument

The `params` argument is provided by the `Autocomplete` component.  It has several members, including some formatting props and some event handlers.

Two of those members are `inputProps` and `InputProps` (notice the difference in capitalization).

- `inputProps` is an object of props for the native `input` element at the innermost level.
- InputProps is an object of props for the `Input` component inside the `TextField`, which is an MUI wrapper around the native `input` element.